# Does $x^n$ have a limit, where $-1<x<0$ and $n$ approaches infinity?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

As the function grow it continues to oscillate at a smaller rate around $0$. Does that justify zero being considered a limit?

Comment: Yes, all $x$ satisfying $-1<x<1$ will follow $x^n \to 0$

Comment: For this kind of problems consider getting back at definition and to work it out.

Comment: To prove a function/sequence tends to $0$, you just have to prove its absolute value tends to $0$. So you can suppose $0<x<1$.

Comment: what about the function not being defined for non-integer values of n?

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct intuition. To make this rigorous, use the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem):

Note that $-1 < -\left(|x|^{n}\right) \leq x^n \leq  |x|^{n} < 1\;\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

From this we see:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} -\left(|x|^{n}\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} |x|^{n} = 0 $$

Hence, $x^n \to 0$ in this case.

Answer (score 0):

$x = \frac{1}{p}$ where $p\in\mathbb{R}^-, p <-1$ thus:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n = \frac{1}{p^n} = 0$

because $p^n$ approaches $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. Either way the limit becomes 0

Comment: The limit varies between $0^+$ or $0^-$. Either way the limit is 0 so it doesn't matter.